# $.ajax doesn't save return breaks

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

```
$.ajax({    
                type: 'get',
                url:  'message.php',
                data: 'msg=' + msg + '&fromname=' + fromname + '&fromemail=' + fromemail,               
                beforeSend: function() {},  
                success: function() { } 
});
```

I use the following method to send the variables through ajax to message.php
message.php then updates the database (mysql) with the '`data`'. the issue I am having is that it changes 2 lines or more into 1 continuous line. so it skips return breaks.
this is the text area :

```
<textarea class="textar" onchange="save();" onclick="this.value=''"  cols="45" rows="5">What would you like to say in the email?</textarea>
```

any ideas please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it into:

```
$.ajax({    
    'type': 'get',
    'url': 'message.php',
    'data': {
        'msg': msg,
        'fromname': fromname,
        'fromemail': fromemail
    },
    'beforeSend': function() {},  
    'success': function() { } 
});
```

which should properly url-encode the values you pass in `data`.

The reason this issue occured is, as I guess, because you have passed a string and therefore you did not rely on jQuery's encoding mechanism.